# How to return column names from SQL database

Tags: c#, sql

Question says it all really, I just want the all column names from a table, I'm looking for as basic way to do this as possible.

Comment: You can query the database schema as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054984/how-can-i-get-column-names-from-a-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get column names from a table in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054984/how-can-i-get-column-names-from-a-table-in-sql-server)

Comment: None of the 16 anwers in the link is what OP most probably want (see answer of pim), so I do not see it as a duplicate.

Comment: Not a duplicate. This question is tagged C# as well as SQL, the "Possible Duplicate" is SQL only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run the following SQL you'll get an empty rowset. From which you can interpret the column names by using a `SqlCommand` and `DataReader`.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("your_conn_string"))
{
    var command = new SqlCommand("select * from [dbo].[tableName] where 1 = 2");
    conn.Open();

    using(var dr = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        var columns = new List<string>();

        for(int i=0;i<reader.FieldCount;i++)
        {
           columns.Add(reader.GetName(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends entirely on the database. Almost all databases have some sort of metadata about the database.  Most implement some version of the `information_schema` method.

For instance, a common way to get information about columns is:

```
select column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = ? and table_schema = ?;
```

`?` are place-holders for the table name and schema.

Comment: He is asking how to do it using C#

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
public string[] getColumnsName()
{
    List<string> listacolumnas=new List<string>();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Connection))
        using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "select c.name from sys.columns c inner join sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.object_id and t.name = 'Usuarios' and t.type = 'U'";
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    listacolumnas.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                }
            }
        }
    return listacolumnas.ToArray();
}
```

[Get column name from SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392331/get-column-name-from-sql-server)