# How can I determine if a DataTable column is unnamed?

Tags: c#, datatable, sqlclient

My subsystem is receiving SQL queries that are to be visualized in tables. I use DataTable because I have no control over the SQL queries that are to be visualized and they can easily be displayed in a DataGrid.

What I basically have is:

```
var query = "SELECT 1";

var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
var table = new DataTable();

adapter.Fill(table);

Console.WriteLine(table.Columns[0].ColumnName);
```

In this case the column name in the DataTable will be set to `Column1` because the input query does not specify a name for the column.

How can I determine if the column name is actually `Column1` or generated by the `SqlDataAdapter` implementation because of the query not specifying the column name?

My first attempt was to check for `Column(N)`, however I realized this is not reliable. What if the query actually specifies the name `Column1`? Also I am worried that "Column" may be translated to something else for a localized version of the .NET framework.

I was also thinking of parsing the input SQL to determine how the columns where named, but this quickly becomes difficult and/or error prone.

Comment: Do any of the answers to [Get column name from SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19392331/get-column-name-from-sql-server) help?

Comment: Not really. While there are multiple solutions to read the column namnes it will require two query executions if you also want the datatable to be filled. I am hoping to find a way to do both with one query.

Comment: You can parse the query. What would be the purpose to know this?

Comment: I want to display something else than ColumnN, like (Unnamed) if it is a column with no name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `SqlDataReader` it is possible to get the actual column names. This is what `SqlDataAdapter` uses. The problem is that the `SqlDataReader` instance it is not accessible from outside of the `SqlDataAdapter`.

My solution is to re-implement the bare required functionality of the `SqlDataAdapter.Fill` method to set the actual column name.

I had to use `Caption` property instead of the `ColumnName` property because the `DataTable` implementation will change the `ColumnName` property value automatically to `Column1` as there seems to be a requirement of the `ColumnName` property to be non-empty and unique.

Minimal `Fill` implementation:

```
var query = "SELECT 1";

var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();

var table = new DataTable();

// Fill
var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

var fieldCount = reader.FieldCount;
for (var index = 0; index < fieldCount; index++)
{
    var name = reader.GetName(index);
    var fieldType = reader.GetFieldType(index);

    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn { ColumnName = name, Caption = name, DataType = fieldType });
}

var valuesBuffer = new object[fieldCount];
while (reader.Read())
{
    reader.GetValues(valuesBuffer);
    table.Rows.Add(valuesBuffer);
}

Console.WriteLine(table.Columns[0].Caption); // Output: <empty string>
```